# Cmake shared lib

Tags: cmake

Как собрать динамическую библиотеку, не редактируя `CMakeLists.txt` ?

Нужна опция при вызове cmake, которая заставляет делать shared obj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON CmakeLists.txt
```